# pop up window with info when image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have 4 images and when I click on one, information about that image should pop up with info about it.

How could I achieve that with jquery? Do I use jQuery for it?

Could someone direct me with some examples I could follow?

Thanks all

Comment: You can do it with jQuery. It's quite easy in fact. Go look at some examples and learn the language.

Comment: You can do it with jQuery, you can do it with JavaScript, you can do it with CSS...

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a popup when clicking ? See how to use JQuery with the `click` event, that's it. Something like

```
$( "#IdPicture" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Here are the different information about the picture" );
});
```

You can also add an `onClick` event to the picture using JS.

You can also use CSS using `#IdPicture:active`

You choose

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it! +1

Comment: Yes and ? You have 3 image so you put 3 alert, that's it. You're using their id so there're 3 ids and so on. You did not provide any code or informations about what you're really trying to do so I can't help you more you know..

Comment: but if you have 20 more images its gona be really long and it's an alert how would I style that

Comment: Then instead of using their id, use the pact that they're all image like `$( "a" ).click();` and display their width or anything you wanna display

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for something like [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). Its quite easy to use. Just browse through the link I provided, in my opinion the examples are quite straight forward. There is also a release based on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/BooooomxD/dkpyy1ka)

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('#popup').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#popup'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

Please have a look, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on hover too

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#box1').hover(function() {
    $('#info1').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0.8
    }, 300)
  }, function() {
    $('#info1').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

  });
  $('#box2').hover(function() {
    $('#info2').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0.8
    }, 300)
  }, function() {
    $('#info2').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

  });
  $('#box3').hover(function() {
    $('#info3').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0.8
    }, 300)
  }, function() {
    $('#info3').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

  });
  $('#box4').hover(function() {
    $('#info4').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0.8
    }, 300)
  }, function() {
    $('#info4').stop().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

  });
});
```

```css
 #box1 {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: blue;
 }
 #box2 {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: red;
 }
 #box3 {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: green;
 }
 #box4 {
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   background: orange;
 }
 #info1 {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #fff;
 }
 #info2 {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #fff;
 }
 #info3 {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #fff;
 }
 #info4 {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box1">
    <div id="info1">
      <p>
        <ul>
          <li>cool info</li>
          <li>even cooler info</li>
          <li>too cool for school info</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <div id="info2">
      <p>
        <ul>
          <li>balblabala</li>
          <li>this is interesting</li>
          <li>of course it is</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <div id="info3">
      <p>
        <ul>
          <li>hello world</li>
          <li>I came to rule the planet</li>
          <li>just kidding</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="box4">
    <div id="info4">
      <p>
        <ul>
          <li>no one will read this anyway</li>
          <li>this is not fun anymore</li>
          <li>finally</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

And of couse with help of css you can position and format the info containers the way you want.